# Which spatial statistics tools to use in examining autocorrelation in two layers?

Tags: spatial-statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compare two spatial point patterns?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4484/how-to-compare-two-spatial-point-patterns)

I am working on a project and have found myself a bit lost as to which types of Spatial Statistics tools I should use to get the results I am looking for.  In short, my project is looking at two different types of crime and whether they are spatially related to one another.  I am interested in seeing if the presence of one type of crime is related to the incidence of the other type of crime. I pulled in two separate point layers into ArcMap for each of the crimes using XY coordinates.  I am planning to study this on a neighborhood level.  I am unsure which tools or statistical functions to use in order to examine this problem.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might glean some useful information from this [post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4484/how-to-compare-two-spatial-point-patterns)