# How to get an indication of how points are spatially distributed?

Tags: python, point, open-source-gis, distribution

Let's say I have a set of points and I want to get an indication of their spatial distribution. That is, if all points are at one location a possible return value would be 0, whereas if all points are distributed evenly the return value would be 1.

The use case: I have two data set which cover the same area. I'm developing a tool to compare both sets with each other. I also want to include a rough indication of the point distribution to detect differences in the sets.

My program will be written in python using open source tools (so no arcgis).

Comment: Maybe this question will help you http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4484/how-to-compare-two-spatial-point-patterns

Comment: This type of analysis can be accomplished using Ripley's K function.  I am not aware of an implementation of Ripley's K in Python directly, however, you may be able to RPy to access the necessary functions in R.  R's spatstat package has everything you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look into spatial point pattern analysis. Here's a course from the world expert that uses R.

http://www.csiro.au/resources/pf16h

I'm not aware of any Python spatial stats library, but you can easily compute things like nearest-neighbour distribution statistics for a quick assessment of whether a point pattern is clustered, completely random, or regularly spaced.

Comment: There is always RPy library for access to R from Python - http://rpy.sourceforge.net/ - if You want to stay in Python. Also see CrimeStat documentation - http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/CrimeStat/ - for many ways to analyse point data - You will get the names of the methods.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to extract the XY coordinates of your points based on whatever GIS you are using, then measure the entropy of your point distribution in a given extent. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) for details about entropy. There is a Python module ([pyentropy](https://code.google.com/p/pyentropy/))for advanced tools