# How can I reproduce Getis-Ord GI* hot-spot analysis tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, analysis, hot-spot

I'm trying to find a hot-spot analysis plug-in for QGIS that would perform similarly to the Getis-Ord (Gi*) hot-spot analysis tool used in Arc, but have not been successful. Does anyone have a suggestion for where to find one?

Answer (score 8):

This question refers to the Getis-Ord GI* hot-spot analysis tool in ArcGIS. One can find an explanation of the tool here:
[http://webhelp.esri.com/ARCGISDESKTOP/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Hot_Spot_Analysis_(Getis-Ord_Gi*)_(Spatial_Statistics)](http://webhelp.esri.com/ARCGISDESKTOP/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Hot_Spot_Analysis_%28Getis-Ord_Gi%2a%29_%28Spatial_Statistics%29)

The assumption that hot-spot is a synonym for heat-map is incorrect. Heat-map has a wide variety of definitions, whereas this question refers to something specific that (to my knowledge) has not been asked or answered before on this forum.

Here is a link to the best guidance I have yet found regarding a plugin in QGIS that is equivalent to the Getis-Ord GI* hot-spot analysis tool in ArcGIS: http://starspy.googlecode.com/svn-history/r348/branches/gph4598f11/qgisplugin/PysalPlugin/getis_ord/getis_ord.py

Answer (score 7):

Though being late to this party (;-) I'd like to point to this prototype which probably answers this thread: [QGIS plugin for hotspot analyis by Stanly Shaji et al.](https://github.com/stanly3690/HotSpotAnalysis_Plugin).

Answer (score 4):

The mentioned prototype was added in the official QGIS repository: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/HotspotAnalysis/

Make sure to read the requirements listed in https://github.com/stanly3690/HotSpotAnalysis_Plugin and don't doubt to ask if any incompatibility arises.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Hot-spot is a synonym for heat-map then this has been asked (and answered) a few times before:

[How to generate heatmaps with QGIS1.9 plugin automatically?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22644/how-to-generate-heatmaps-with-qgis1-9-plugin-automatically)

and

[How to build effective heat-maps?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256/how-to-build-effective-heat-maps/307#307)

Comment: Definitely not a synonym for heatmap! Heatmaps are typically about creating a raster interpolation of the density of observations given point data. Hotspot analysis is about locating areas of statistically significant geospatial clusters of observations with a particular attribute within a larger sample population. Put more simply, if we were mapping crime, a heatmap could let us see where crime is taking place, full stop; a hotspot analysis could show where crime is taking place at higher than expected levels given the existing population.