# Emerging hotspot analysis (space-time patterns) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatio-temporal-data, spatial-analysis, hot-spot

I worked with crime data a while ago and was really impressed by the possibility in ArcGIS to detect significant hotspots and their development over time (Emerging hotspot analysis).

Does anybody know if there is a similar function in QGIS or a plugin?

[image: Example of a previous emerging hotspot analysis I've done]

Comment: This is out of my knowledge, but did you check this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24175/how-can-i-reproduce-getis-ord-gi-hot-spot-analysis-tool-in-qgis and this qgis plugin https://github.com/danioxoli/HotSpotAnalysis_Plugin?

Comment: The tool you recommended is already a great help since it provides the possiblity to conduct more statistically advanced analyses regarding hotspots. Nevertheless, it doesn't incorporate the space-time dimension I'm looking for. I'm in need of a tool similar to this one: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/space-time-pattern-mining-toolbox/emerginghotspots.htm