# Making heat maps using ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, heat-map

I want to prepare the heat maps so what parameters are required for that??

I have large point data (I want to represent the density on the map)

I gone through the following posts :

- [How to build effective heat-maps?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256)
- http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/43069-How-to-create-a-heat-map-from-shapefile-data

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 and ArcGIS Server 10.1 + ArcGIS Java Script API 3.0

Comment: Slightly unrelated: http://xkcd.com/1138/ :)

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @ NWT Adam I have large point data which contains attribute information so how do I create the heat map?? I understand that it represents density on the map.(point shape file published on ArcGIS Server & created the REST url)so how do represent it on heat map..? thanks

Comment: Do I need to calculate any formula for that ?

Comment: Those links no longer work though. Any idea where they should go now? Thanx! Zeddock

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @zeddock Please give us detail. Which link does not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coincidentally, I have been doing a lot of reading about this subject over the last couple of days.  For the actual generation of heat maps there are a large number of factors to consider.

The most valuable resources for me were from Laura Rosenshein at Esri.
She sums up a lot of the material in [this one blog post.](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/07/13/spatial-statistics-resources/)

To answer your question, I would recommend watching the videos linked on that page and then running through the tutorial - that gave me sufficient knowledge on how to use the Spatial Statistics tools in ArcMap to create a multi scale-level heat map for my web application.

If you are short on time, this [post](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/analysis/017z00000015000000.htm) gives a good summary on considerations to think about when creating a heat map.

Comment: links didn't work. I think this is the new link to the first one: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/03/31/taking-analysis-to-the-next-level-part-1/

Answer (score 4):

It might also be worth checking out this library which is hosted on the new ESRI github. The library allows you to make a heat map on the client side using HTML5.

A demo of the application: http://esri.github.io/heatmap-layer-js/

The github site: https://github.com/Esri/heatmap-layer-js

Comment: @David...thanks for your reply those are useful links for heat map..thanks: )

Answer (score 0):

Updating this in 2021: the latest ArcGIS API for JavaScript v4 has a [heatmap renderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-renderers-HeatmapRenderer.html). Sample is here: [Visualize points with a heatmap](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/visualization-heatmap/).

Example:

```js
const renderer = {
  type: "heatmap",
  colorStops: [
    { color: "rgba(63, 40, 102, 0)", ratio: 0 },
    { color: "#472b77", ratio: 0.083 },
    { color: "#4e2d87", ratio: 0.166 },
    { color: "#563098", ratio: 0.249 },
    { color: "#5d32a8", ratio: 0.332 },
    { color: "#6735be", ratio: 0.415 },
    { color: "#7139d4", ratio: 0.498 },
    { color: "#7b3ce9", ratio: 0.581 },
    { color: "#853fff", ratio: 0.664 },
    { color: "#a46fbf", ratio: 0.747 },
    { color: "#c29f80", ratio: 0.83 },
    { color: "#e0cf40", ratio: 0.913 },
    { color: "#ffff00", ratio: 1 }
  ],
  maxPixelIntensity: 25,
  minPixelIntensity: 0
};

const layer = new CSVLayer({
  url: "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.csv",
  title: "Magnitude 2.5+ earthquakes from the last week",
  renderer: renderer
});
```