# Weighted heatmap analysis- density of points, vs density of weight variable

Tags: qgis, heat-map, kernel-density

Was just wondering if anyone could help me with a problem. I'm trying to map wellbeing scores (out of 10), using locations from a survey of 15,000 households, using the HEatmap command in QGIS. It's an unclustered sample, but obviously the density of points is dependent on the population density of the area. I'm using wellbeing score as a weight in the heatmap, but unfortunately every map I produce is effectively a map of population density. I have tried multiple ways of weighting the wellbeing score to factor in the differing densities of points (so scores in areas with only a few data points are weighted, up and scores in dense areas are weighted down), but the heatmap looks effectively the same every time.
Is there any sensible way of doing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Please read [How to build effective heat-maps?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256/how-to-build-effective-heat-maps)

It seems like you are looking for **Distributions of attribute values** rather than **Concentration of points**. Therefore, the QGIS heatmap plugin is the wrong tool for the job since it only does concentration of points.

Try **Raster | Analysis | Grid (Interpolation)** instead.

Another solution could be to first generate a vector grid - could be a hex grid if you like it fancy - and then calculate e.g. the average wellbeing score for each cell and map that.

Comment: For at least QGIS 3.10 and above, this command is now in the Processing Toolbox, under `Interpolation`, and is named `IDW Interpolation`.

Comment: Although, for reference, this might take a while. I have a point layer that takes about five minutes to render (normally, using the layer symbology setting) as a heatmap. The above-mentioned IDW Interpolation algorithm got 5% of the way through (with the default resolution settings) in around an hour.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this post is a year old, but I came across it when looking up information on kernel density estimations with QGIS.  I've not tried this yet, but it appears from the QGIS documentation that the [Heatmap Plugin](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_heatmap.html?highlight=heatmap) can make use of the attributes of the original points via the "Use weight from field" option.

(would love to hear back from anyone with experience with this)

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE. It appears that you are asking a question in an answer to another question? You are much more likely to get a positive response if you framed your own question specifically, or changed you answer to actually answer the original question asked with some more relevant information and examples. You could have added you response as a Comment, however, rather than an answer to see if you could get any more information.

Comment: welcome to GIS@SE. This should really be a new question or a comment.